# The program don’t seem to work if there is a duplicate number in the array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, if-statement

If the user searches a number within the array, the system should print out the index that the number is located, if not it would print out search not found. As of now, it works only if there are no duplicate numbers in the array.

I tried removing the **break** but that would stop the program from printing the second index that also contains the search number.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int[] array = new int[10];
        array[0] = 6;
        array[1] = 2;
        array[2] = 8;
        array[3] = 1;
        array[4] = 3;
        array[5] = 0;
        array[6] = 9;
        array[7] = 8;

        System.out.print("Search for? ");
        int searching = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());
      
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            int input = array[i];
            if (searching == input) {
                System.out.println(searching + " is at index " + i);
                break;
                
            }
            else if (searching != array[i] && i == (array.length - 1))
            {
                System.out.println(searching+" was not found!");
                break;
            }
            

        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
         Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
         int[] array = {6,2,8,1,3,0,9,8};
         System.out.print("Search for? ");
         int searching = scanner.nextInt();
         ArrayList positions=new ArrayList();
         for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
             int input = array[i];
             if (searching == input) {
                 positions.add(i);
             }
         }
         if(positions.size()>0) {
             for(int x=0;x<positions.size();x++) {
                 System.out.println(searching+" is at index "+ positions.get(x));
             }
         }
         else {
             System.out.println(searching+" was not found!");
         }
```

To receive an int with a scanner it is easier to use the nextInt () method. In the first for you can accumulate the positions where the number that is searched for in an arraylist matches, then you check that the arraylist is not empty and you print all the positions in which the number has been found. If the list is empty, the message of not found is printed.